# AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'options'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to build a model using elasticsearch in python but I am getting this error, I was able to execute it once but now I cannot run it again due to this error

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("salaries.csv")
df.head()

inputs = df.drop('salary_more_then_100k',axis='columns')

target = df['salary_more_then_100k']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le_company = LabelEncoder()
le_job = LabelEncoder()
le_degree = LabelEncoder()

inputs['company_n'] = le_company.fit_transform(inputs['company'])
inputs['job_n'] = le_job.fit_transform(inputs['job'])
inputs['degree_n'] = le_degree.fit_transform(inputs['degree'])

inputs

inputs_n = inputs.drop(['company','job','degree'],axis='columns')

inputs_n

target

from sklearn import tree
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

model.fit(inputs_n, target)

from eland.ml import MLModel
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(hosts='http://localhost:9200')

es_model = MLModel.import_model(es_client=es,
                                model=model,
                                model_id='salaries-model',
                                feature_names=list(df.columns),
                                es_if_exists='replace'
)
```

When I run the es_model line, I get this error -> AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'options'

What am I doing wrong, Can anyone please tell me

Answer (score 0):

This came up for me after I installed the elasticsearch-dsl package. my Elastic packages got out of synch with the elasticsearch library at a much lower release than elastic_transport. Upgrading the elasticsearch library fixed my issues.

Comment: Hi crash, welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for answering this old question. To make your most useful, could you add steps you used to upgrade the elasticsearch library?

Comment: I am using PyCharm for my Python devdlopment with virtual environments for each project. In PyCharm under File -> Settings there is a Python Interpreter display that shows the packages & versions.  They use a triangle icon to show packages that have updates available and you can click the icon to update.  This also made it easy to see a major version difference between my Elastic packages.  More generally, the pip command 'pip list --outdated' will list all outdated packages.  From the pip list you can use the standard pip --upgrade command.